# Magento 2 admin this webpage has a redirect loop

Tags: magento2, admin

Magento 2 was just released last night and, I can't wait to work on it.
I tried installing it with all prerequisites.

Frontend works fine. But when I tried to open the backend, it says "this webpage has a redirect loop".
Magento created "admin_r2sxkn" as a unique backend URL.
My Admin URL is http://localhost/magento2/admin_r2sxkn

As a solution, I tried deleting the cache which did not work.

P.S I have xampp on mac, with the latest versions of PHP and MySql, installed PHP extension incl as required.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A browser does not support cookies on top-level domains like localhost. Please reinstall Magento on a different hostname (ex. magento.dev).

Also, Magento supports only Linux. So better to use [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) for development. You can use any exists [preconfiguret vagrant instance](https://github.com/search?q=magento2%20vagrant&ref=reposearch&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93) that do all work for you

Comment: Magento supports only Linux?

Comment: @BhargavNanekalva, yes https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Comment: It may work on Linux-like operating systems like macOS (many people do do that for development; see for example https://github.com/weprovide/valet-plus). It's not officially supported, however, so there could be unexpected incompatibilities.

Answer (score 31):

In my case, I was importing an already existing Magento 2 database.  The reason I was getting the error was because of the cookie domain in the database.  Go to your database and look in the table `core_config_data`.  You should see a path called `web/cookie/cookie_domain`.  Make sure the domain matches the one you installed Magento 2 on.  Ex:  If you installed Magento 2 on `local.dev/<magento-root>`  the entry in `web/cookie/cookie_domain` should be `local.dev`.

Comment: This was my issue as well...

Comment: that is mail  reason

Comment: select * from core_config_data where path like "web/%";

Answer (score 20):

Had redirect loop problem on Magento2 with a valid domain name after switching to https.

Check `web/secure/use_in_adminhtml` and `web/secure/use_in_frontend` settings in `core_config_data`, they both should be set to `1`.

Comment: Thank you elene you saved our hell of a time. it worked for me.
query to see values: `select * from core_config_data where path like 'web/%';`

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Also, if it's more convenient to do this from the command line rather than editing records in the database, it's
`magento config:set web/secure/use_in_adminhtml 1` and
`magento config:set web/secure/use_in_frontend 1`

Comment: My hero! ;-) That was exactly what I needed.

Comment: There still one step left - to delete cach: `rm -rf var/cache var/generation var/page_cache`

Answer (score 9):

while installing magento2 on your localhost try to use 127.0.0.1 in the your store address in step 3 instead of the localhost. now what can you do is in core_config_data table change following 2 rows

```
web/unsecure/base_url to http://127.0.0.1/magento2/
web/secure/base_url to https://127.0.0.1/magento2/
```

clear cache and check now

Edited:-

While installing try 127.0.0.1 in the your store address in step 3 as shown in the screenshot

[image]

Comment: I made the same changes,magento2 admin now working with firefox but not with chrome, i also clear cache,but no result

Answer (score 6):

I had a domain of the form local.abc_def.com and I was experiencing this issue.

I changed the underscore in the domain to be a hyphen, resulting in a domain of local.abc-def.com and this fixed the issue for me

Comment: Rally appreciable :)

Answer (score 5):

Try to clean var/cache folder. It helps me.

Comment: +1 That was my issue too when trying to setup a live site on local,copied the var/cache folder by mistake.

Answer (score 5):

Can be debugged in \Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Auth\Login::execute

For example with

```
    $requestUrl = $this->getRequest()->getUri();
    $backendUrl = $this->getUrl('*');
    // redirect according to rewrite rule
    echo (string)$requestUrl . ' != ' . $backendUrl;
    die();
```

It is dies and the URLs are different, this give a hint to the problem.

Comment: I'm having almost the same problem as the OP but checking these vars just raises further questions - the two URLs never match, because the key is different on each, every time. If I try to load a URL without a key (just `admin/` for example) it checks that against the URL with a key and redirects... to another URL with a key, which is checked against a URL which then has another different key??

Comment: Right, appears to be some bug/misconfiguration around using a custom admin URL - resetting this to 'admin' in env.php resolved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

After switching http to https need to update following values in core_config_data table.

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = REPLACE(value, '0', '1') WHERE path = 'web/secure/use_in_frontend';

UPDATE core_config_data SET value = REPLACE(value, '0', '1') WHERE path = 'web/secure/use_in_adminhtml';
```

Then Clear caches and reload admin URL.

Comment: Why do you `SET value = REPLACE(value, '0', '1')` instead of `SET value = '1'`?

Answer (score 1):

I've spent 8 hours on the topic, here are my conclusions

1) set **AllowOverride all** at apache directory configuration, at least to get .htaccess file to be readen, on the magento folder is the universal solution for getting the frontoffice && backoffice to work

2) set **RewriteBase /** in .htaccess or a subfolder if localhost/magento

3) Be sure to use https for the admin path in case those requests might proove handy ( otherwise the admin cookie won't set at all ) :

d=**magento.yourdomain.localhost**;

mysql -u a -pb -e "UPDATE magento.core_config_data SET value = '**https**://$d/' WHERE path in('web/secure/base_url')";

mysql -u a -pb -e "UPDATE magento.core_config_data SET **value=1** WHERE path in('**web/secure/use_in_adminhtml**')"

php bin/magento cache:flush

4) That's all, I've removed all the wrong guess from this post, as they were a lot in a first glance ..

Answer (score 1):

If you use Varnish, do not forget to set:

`RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"`

in virtual host configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Addiotionally to all the other answers, double check the URLs in your app/etc/env.php - they override configuration from the database:

```
'web' => [
    'unsecure' => [
        'base_url' => 'https://my.shop/',
    ],
    'secure' => [
        'base_url' => 'https://my.shop/',
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a better solution to fix the above issue.

Open the **.htaccess** file

find the line

```
 #RewriteBase /magento/
```

According to your problem, 
Uncomment the line as

```
  RewriteBase /magento2/
```

Note-: Save the .htaccess file
Clean all the var/cache and browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

Before installation, You must choose a valid domain name. For example: `www.magento2-test.dev` instead `localhost`. More details for this issue: [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2473)

Answer (score 0):

Use `localhost` as an actual top level domain instead of standalone and you should be able to manage this. Using `.dev` is not a good idea as explained in this article: https://iyware.com/dont-use-dev-for-development/

`http://magento.localhost/` would be suitable or if you have some `DOMAIN.com` that it will be deployed to later, you can do `DOMAIN.localhost` which later will end up at DOMAIN.com and then you can code your web server to look for the hostname regardless of TLD you use.

e.x. if you have two stores at DOMAIN1.com and DOMAIN2.com enter your rules in nginx conf (or whatever your web server of choice) as `DOMAIN1.*` for code evaluating DOMAIN1 specific code. Apache you might use something like `SetEnvIf Host DOMAIN1\.(localhost|com)$ VAR=val` in your `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0):

In some scenarios deleting the cookies specific to the Magento2 installation and clearing Magento cache files in `var/cache` will resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should  delete var/cache/* and run setup:static-content:deploy command.
it should be work.
I solved this issue on my localhost with above step

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to look out for is that your web server engine (nginx/apache) listens on SSL port 443 and that you have certificates configured. This was the issue for me together with advice already stated in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing cache `bin/magento cache:clean`

and

`bin/magento cache:flush`

Answer (score 0):

This admin redirection loop can also occur if you've not setup the cookie domain properly in the admin, you can update it via admin in `Store -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Default Cookie setting -> Cookie Domain`    or using following cli command.

```
php bin/magento config:set web/cookie/cookie_domain your_top_level_domain
```