# Magento 2.0 admin not working in chrome

Tags: magento2

[image]

i am unable to open the admin login panel in chrome ,but the admin login panel is working in Firefox ,  thanks in advanve.

Comment: refer my answer at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90456/magento-2-admin-this-webpage-has-a-redirect-loop/90463#90463

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a virtual host, and then it will work.

```
-Open the XAMPP Control Panel. ...

-Click Start button next to Apache to restart the server.

-To test your virtual host, create the following in a text editor and save it as site_check.php in the C:\vhosts\in234 folder.

-Stop both Apache and MySQL servers.

-Click Quit to close the XAMPP Control Panel.
```

Comment: Use HTTP Only is "yes"

Comment: stores->web->default cookie setting->use http only->"yes"   (magento 2.0)

Comment: its not working after use http only to yes.same error display.

Comment: Are you on wamp, or xampp?