# Magento 2 admin catalog category page isn't redirecting properly

Tags: magento2, admin, category, redirect

I'm **migrating** a website from **Magento 1.9.0.1 to 2.2**, I've only migrated data, that's all I need, the migration completed sucessfully, all the products, customers, orders, categories are there, all pages of the admin section are working fine but the Category one, it has a redirect loop apparently.

I've looked into `core_config_data` both base url are pointing to http://127.0.0.1/magento/ and web/secure/use_in_adminhtml is set to 0.

Already cleaned the cache and reindexed everything.

This [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/144239/24110) said to check `web/cookie/cookie_domain` my `core_config_data` didn't have this path, so I tried adding it, but no joy.

I've migrated two different shops from 1.9.0.1 to 2.2 and had the exact same problem.

Comment: `, all pages of the admin section are working fine but the Category one,` admin category pages does not opening ?

Comment: Yes, Category page is not loading, it has a redirecting problem.

Comment: how can u resolve this issue? @HermanoVarussa

Answer (score 2):

You need to select Root Category for your Store, This will solve your issues.