# Magento 2 admin login redirection loop

Tags: magento2, login, redirect

- Magento 2.2.4
- Store set up on subdomain: `dev.store.com`
- SSL
- Config variables:

> web/unsecure/base_url - https://dev.store.com/
>
> web/unsecure/base_web_url - {{unsecure_base_url}}
>
> web/unsecure/base_link_url - {{unsecure_base_url}}
>
> web/secure/base_url - https://dev.store.com/
>
> web/secure/use_in_frontend -
>
> web/secure/use_in_adminhtml - 1
>
> web/secure/base_web_url - {{secure_base_url}}
>
> web/secure/offloader_header - X-Forwarded-Proto
>
> web/secure/base_link_url - {{secure_base_url}}

I get the admin login page ok. After providing login credentials website gets into a **redirection** loop. As I can see it's redirected from:

```
dev.store/com/admin_123/admin/dashboard/index/key/
```

to

```
dev.store/com/admin_123/admin/system_account/
```

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Can you check your web/cookie/cookie_path and web/cookie/cookie_domain settings? These should be set to / and your domain respectively (Or adjust path as needed of course).

Comment: Neither of those exists in my config system. When I try to set them I get "invalid domain name" error

Comment: Is that with the following values?
web/cookie/cookie_path = /
web/cookie/cookie_domain = dev.store.com

Comment: I've set it as suggested, but it didn't help...

Comment: Ok, maybe have a look through these answers then: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90456/magento-2-admin-this-webpage-has-a-redirect-loop/90462

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related with account I was trying to log in with. For some reason Magento didn't like it. I created new admin user and logged in ok with the new one. Just letting you know that it might be worth checking before going any deeper into it.